# How to list posts that appear in two categories

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I would like to list all posts that appear in the current category being viewed that are also posted to a second category.

Example Pictures : [LINK](http://tiny.cc/phkwqw)

For instance, a listing of the common posts between the Headline category and the Media category if Media is currently being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need is this, [from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'category__and' => 
    array( 2, 6 ) 
  ) 
);
```

Where the numbers (2, 6) are your category IDs. Your question does not have enough detail, or enough code, for me to tell you how to implement that inot your page.

Comment: Thank you for answer s_ha_dum.. I want this dynamic (cat id)..So if i in Media category, then i want see this in sidebar, Headline and Media post list, if in internet then i want see Headline and Internet post list ( common post list) sorry for bad english..

Comment: Yes, I know what you want but you didn't post any code so that is about the best I can do.

Comment: Ok thanx all answer